# How to split twitter streaming data and append the text to csv file?

Tags: python, twitter, split, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I have a script that streams twitter data filtered by one keyword. It streams the data into a csv file but the tweets have a multitude of objects attached to it e.g. Id, created_at, text, source etc.

I only need a few of these objects to append to the csv file but even after splitting the data and appending only the text object, some tweets appear with all the tweet objects appended. It seems the tweets that are retweets splits fine, normal tweets however do not split.

This is my code:

```
ckey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
csecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
atoken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
asecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def dateRange(start, end):
    current = start
    while(end - current).days >=0:
        yield current
        current = current + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1)


class Tweetlistener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        startdate = datetime.datetime(2016,6,1)
        enddate = datetime.datetime(2016,6,7)
        for date in dateRange(startdate, enddate):
            try:
                ##This is where I split the data
                tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]


                saveThis = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
                saveFile = open('test.csv', 'a')
                saveFile.write(saveThis)
                saveFile.write('\n')
                return True
            except ValueError:
                print("Something went wrong with streaming")
        saveFile.close()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


twitterStream = Stream(auth, Tweetlistener(), secure = True)
twitterStream.filter(track=['brexit'])
```

This is the result in the csv file
[image: The first cell is a retweet and it splits as i intend it to, the cell below isn't a retweet and it appends all tweet objects]

The first cell is a retweet and it splits as i intend it to, the cell below isn't a retweet and it appends all tweet objects.

How would I be able to split the data and only append the text, created_at, retweet_count, location, co-ordinates?

EDIT:

This is the raw data thats put in to one row per tweet (not my data, just an example i found online):

```
{
 'contributors': None, 
 'truncated': False, 
 'text': 'My Top Followers in 2010: @tkang1 @serin23 @uhrunland @aliassculptor @kor0307 @yunki62. Find yours @ http://mytopfollowersin2010.com',
 'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 'id': 21041793667694593,
 '_api': ,
 'author': ,
 'retweeted': False,
 'coordinates': None,
 'source': 'My Top Followers in 2010',
 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
 'id_str': '21041793667694593',
 'retweet_count': 0,
 'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
 'favorited': False,
 'retweeted_status': ,
 'source_url': 'http://mytopfollowersin2010.com', 
 'user': ,
 'geo': None, 
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 3, 15, 29), 
 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, 
 'place': None
```

}

I would want my data to be one tweet per row in this kind of format:

```
"created_at":Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008::"text"::Example tweet::"retweet_count":154::"favorite_count":200::"coordinates":[-75.14310264,40.05701649]
```

Where '::' differentiates the objects.

Comment: Do you really need a CSV? I would imagine JSON would be better if you have a nested structure. And the fact that you seem to be using `split()` instead of parsing JSON objects, can be an issue

Comment: @cricket_007 for familiarity sake I went with CSV

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the raw data, as text? Before the split? And also include what you would like to look like after?

Comment: @cricket_007 the post has been updated with the raw data and what i would like it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting JSON data, so naturally, viewing such a file in Excel as a CSV is a bad idea.

So is this line

```
tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
```

You need to instead parse the keys. For example

```
import json, csv 

def on_data(self, data):
    tweet = json.loads(data) 
    text = tweet["text"]
    source = tweet["source"]
    with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([text, source])
```

The idea is rather than slice the string apart based on certain strings, actually use its existing structure to your advantage, then extract the necessary fields, by name

Sidenote, personally I find that opening and closing a file for every message is operationally expensive, so I would suggest finding a way to only do that once the stream starts and stops

Comment: The structure of the data string has been edited into the post and I added the format i want to parse the data into

Comment: this code works with my script however after writing a few tweets to the csv file, it keeps triggering the except block. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok this one works, just needed to remove the try and except block and add encoding="utf-8" to 'with open line' so it becomes: with open('test.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8")as f:

Answer (score 2):

You can use json decoder to do the job

```
import json
required_fields = [u'text', u'created_at', u'retweet_count', u'place',  u'coordinates']

......

      data = data.decode('utf-8')
      json_data = json.loads(data) # this is dict
      tweet = '::'.join([i+':'+unicode(json_data[i]) for i in required_fields])
```

Comment: Where would this code snippet go in the above code provided? I tried putting the code (the last line throws an error) in the try block but i get invalid syntax